# Custom theme show Notice Undefined variable: wp_query in function.php

Tags: php, wordpress, function

I have a code in `function.php` for showing pagination in a custom theme [index page](http://templategraphy.com/wp-demo/businessguru/) but it shows two errors in same line `$wp_query`

- `Undefined variable: wp_query in function.php`
- `Trying to get property of non-object in function.php`

my function:

```
function getpagenavi(){
        ?>
<div id="pagination" class="clearfix">
<?php
 if (function_exists('wp_pagenavi')): ?>
<?php
 wp_pagenavi()  ?>
<?php  else : ?>
        <div class="alignleft">  
        <a href="<?php $max = $wp_query->max_num_pages; previous_posts();?>" class="classname" title="Previous post">Previous post</a></div>
        <div class="alignright"><a href="<?php  next_posts($max);?>" class="classname" title="Next post">Next post</a></div>
        <div class="clear"></div>
<?php
 endif; ?>
</div>
<?php
    }
```

What can I do to correct this error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using `$wp_query->max_num_pages` when `$wp_query` is not defined within that function scope.

Pretending you know what `wp_query` is supposed to be at the point where that function is called, you can add the following line at the top of the `getpagenavi` function:

```
Global $wp_query;
```

or better, pass it as a parameter:

```
// where you call the function assuming $wp_query exists there.
getpagenavi($wp_query);

// your function
function getpagenavi($wp_query){
```

Comment: Some answers are so useful that I even log in to thank you! :)

Answer (score 1):

Make `WP_Query` as a global variable:

```
<?php

    global $wp_query;

    echo 'Results: ' . $wp_query->found_posts;

?>
```